# i can't pin anything to start

Tags: apps

I am not able to pin any app from the right hand list to the start screen. I tap and hold the app and the white "pin to start" option appears but nothing happens when I hit it. Help!

Comment: Never  saw something like this.

Comment: Can you please provide more details such as which phone you have, as well as any other information such as if you've ever been able to pin anything. What have you tried pinning?

Comment: Have you tried to reset your phone? In settings and about.

Comment: Also, how much stuff is already pinned to the start screen?